# How do I make this javascript async while loop work?

Tags: javascript, google-dfp

I'm attempting to get a google gpt tag to refresh a maximum number of times if, when loaded, it comes back empty.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    var slot1 = googletag.defineSlot("/gtpConfigStuff",[300,600],"gtpConfigStuff")
    .addService(googletag.pubads())
    .setTargeting("pos", "BTF")
    .setTargeting("URL", encodeURIComponent(window.location));
    googletag.enableServices();
    googletag.display("gtpConfigStuff");
    googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
    var tries = 0;
    while (tries<=2 && event.isEmpty==true) {
    //googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]);
    //setTimeout(function() {
      tries++;
      console.log(tries);
      //}, 1000);
      }
      console.log("done");
     });
  });
 </script>
```

With the above lines commented out it works as it should.
With the refresh function call it will loop indefinitely.
The setTimeout I thought might allow the refresh to finish.

Thanks.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, adding #setTimeout breaks functionality. The reason is because #setTimeout doesn't work as you think --- it does *not* pause. Instead, think of it as starting a new thread. See JS event loop and stack.

Comment: oh ok. That won't help then.  If I remove that bit it simply loops forever.

Comment: t will probably load indefinitely because googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]); calls the event slotRenderEnded which refreshes googletag.pubads which calls the event slotRenderEnded which refreshes googletag.pubads which calls the event slotRenderEnded which refreshes googletag.pubads which calls the event slotRenderEnded which refreshes googletag.pubads which calls the event slotRenderEnded which refreshes googletag.pubads which calls the event slotRenderEnded see where I'm going with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script will load indefinitely because you're resetting your `tries` variable indefinitely

```
var tries = 0; // Set your variable here...
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
  // ...and not here. Otherwise it will always reset to 0 when the event triggers.
  // "tries" will still be available in here though as a closure so you can still use it
  if (tries<=2 && event.isEmpty==true) {
    googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]);
    tries++;
  }
});
```